# How to push skb in specific point of Linux network stack?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to push skb to `prerouting` point of Linux network stack. Is there any way to do this?
I used `dev_queue_xmit()`  and `netif_rx()` functions, but I don't think they can push skb in `prerouting` point of Linux network stack.

[image]

Comment: could you be more elaborate with the kernel version please? Its hard to be specific without the kernel version

Comment: @Pegasus I'm using kernel 3.2

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Want to push skb to prerouting from where? Could you please elaborate

Comment: I want to register ioctl in prerouting point, then from user space I will send packets via SEND_PACKET(buffer, size) ioctl.

Comment: @Khajavi In according to send packets a simple send() syscall is enough, I don't know why you want it in that way. You can use the concept of netfilter hooking to invoke at prerouting point, you can do function hooking and can do anything you want at that point. I think you need to take a look at netfilter tutorials.

Comment: @rakib send packet couldn't fulfill my requirements. Hook means, when a situation occurred (when a packet received) specific function will called. but I don't need hook, I need to implement something like ioctl, that I can send packets from user space, and then in kernel, receive them and push them in prerouting point of Linux network stack.

Comment: @Khajavi I'd insist you to take a look at netfilter tutorials. If you register a hook at prerouting path, *every packet* will invoked your hooking function.

Comment: @rakib Yes I know than I can create netfilter hook and get every packet that come to prerouting point (as I have do it).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear *where* this skb originates from. In userland, there are two ways to do this. One is to use a `tun` device (and simply write the packet in). The other is to use `libpcap` (which has the little known feature of sending raw packets hidden amongst all the receive stuff).

You say you want to do this by registering an `ioctl` (presumably meaning adding your own `ioctl`) then calling the `ioctl` from user space. It isn't immediately obvious why you would want to do that when you can already achieve this without modifying the kernel. However, if you did want to do this, what I'd do is follow the path the `tun` driver uses, and do the equivalent of `write()`-ing to the `tun` device in your new `ioctl`. That might mean having a `tun`-like interface hanging around to act as the source for the packets. I suspect packets in the system *need* a source interface of sorts.

Comment: This the payload of packet is created from user space, then I want to ioctl this packet to my kernel module, then I get the packet from user space, know I allocate new skb and add packet payload to it, know I need to push skb to prerouting point of network stack.

Comment: Why do you think that `netif_rx()` is wrong in this case then? This (or more precisely `netif_rx_ni()`) is exactly what `drivers/net/tun.c` uses, and prerouting definitely works for `tun`. I suspect your problem is, however, not that you are calling the wrong function but that unless your `skb` is tracked as coming from an interface (which yours isn't) the prerouting stuff may not work as you intend it to (consider how prerouting rules that examine the input interface would work). This is why I suggested using a `tun` device and no kernel changes.

Comment: @abligh: I skb_copy() my skb in netfilter's pre-routing hook handler, modify its data and want to re-inject it back - next to the original skb. So that each received packet to be transformed into 2 packets routed separately. I tried to stick the copied skb to legitimate one via linked list prior to returning NF_ACCEPT, but it didn't work out. Any idea how to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want libpcap or libnetfilter_queue hereafter collectively referred to as userland queuing. Userland queuing will route all packets matching some rule (you define) to your userland application. The dev_queue_* and netif_* functions apply to kernel level routing and are not relevant to userland applications.

Userland queuing has performance implications and depending on the library you use you will have to use a specific method of re-injecting your packet back into the netfilter queues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is `ip_queue_xmit()`, which is where IPV4 implementation starts checking tables, filters, etc.